# Have any studies been done into any links between the use of lead in petrol and dementia

Tags: dementia

I noticed in a recent article that the number of people getting dementia has been falling. This fall has been masked our increasing lifespan. When this factor is adjusted for the rate has apparently been falling for 20 to 30 years. This seems very close to the number of years that lead in petrol has been banned.

Comment: Hi Michael Mcgarry, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: I wanted to know is any studies had been done as I couldn't find any. Lack of response here suggests there are none. My question has been answered so do as you wish

Comment: "No one answered my question in 3 hours" is a rather questionable way of building knowledge about the world, but go ahead. Did you try searching for the words "lead petrol dementia" in a place where one might find papers, like Pubmed or Google Scholar? If not, what do you mean by "I couldn't find any"?

Comment: Actually I just did and I must apologise. I was just being lazy. I have now found many articles on the subject.

Comment: Remember to do the same search using "gasoline" instead of "petrol."